# Image to zip in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Currently, I'm using the below code but it's giving me a currupt zip file..

```
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://mattfarmer.net/projects/thickbox/images/plant4.jpg')
f = StringIO()
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'w')
zip.writestr('plant4.jpg', url.read())
response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type="application/zip")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=plant4bar.zip'
return response
```

Comment: On a side note, have you compared the zipped file size to the original jpg? jpg is already a compressed format so I wouldn't expect the file size to decrease by much when zipping.

Answer (score 2):

You should close your zip file

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import urllib2
from StringIO import StringIO
import zipfile

def home(request):
    url = urllib2.urlopen('http://mattfarmer.net/projects/thickbox/images/plant4.jpg')
    f = StringIO()
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'w')
    zip.writestr('plant4.jpg', url.read())
    zip.close() # Close
    response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type="application/zip")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=plant4bar.zip'
    return response
```